# How to break from Future.compose chain in-between in Vertx

Tags: java, vert.x

I am trying to use Future.Compose functionality in Vertx to execute some sequential code.
but I am stuck in-between where i want to break from chain.

```
    Future<JsonObject> fut1 = func1(abc, xyz);
    fut1.compose(fut1Result -> {
      LOGGER.debug("Success");
      return fut2();
    }).compose(fut2Result -> {
      if (fut2Result.containsKey("detail")) {
        // although future is succedded, but it logically failed.
        // So here i am trying yo break from this Future.compose chain ? how to break.
        LOGGER.error("Errorfailed. ");
        promise.tryFail(new Throwable(fut2Result.toString()));
      }
      LOGGER.debug("Success");
      return fut3();
    }).compose(fut3Result -> {
      LOGGER.debug("Success");
      return fut4();
    }).onSuccess(success -> {
      LOGGER.debug("Success");
      promise.complete();
    }).onFailure(failure -> {
      LOGGER.error("Error");
      promise.fail(failure.getCause());
    });
```

One way is to refactor my **fut2()** function. Is there any method to break from Future.compose chain.
I have tried `promise.fail()` , `promise.tryFail()` & tried to throw a `Throwable` directly but nothing worked.

hints in right direction will be very helpful.

Comment: Solved the problem by just returning Future.failedFuture(result) for stopping other compose functions to execute

Answer (score 1):

When there is a failure, instead of returning `fut3`, return a [failed `Future`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Future.html#failedFuture-java.lang.String-):

```
Future<JsonObject> fut1 = func1(abc, xyz);
fut1.compose(fut1Result -> {
  LOGGER.debug("Success");
  return fut2();
}).compose(fut2Result -> {
  if (fut2Result.containsKey("detail")) {
    LOGGER.error("Errorfailed. ");
    return Future.failedFuture(fut2Result.toString());
  }
  LOGGER.debug("Success");
  return fut3();
}).compose(fut3Result -> {
  LOGGER.debug("Success");
  return fut4();
}).onSuccess(success -> {
  LOGGER.debug("Success");
  promise.complete();
}).onFailure(failure -> {
  LOGGER.error("Error");
  promise.fail(failure.getCause());
});
```